# Create factory which creates classes from different namespaces

Tags: php, oop, factory-pattern

I have a question regarding the dynamic creation of classes using a factory.
Let's say I have have a core namespace where a framework's base classes lie. And besides that I have a namespace for the app specific files. Now I have a factory in the cores namespace which I would use to create for example a validator class. Now there are validators which belong to the framework and validators which are application specific.

Besides that I have an autoloader which resolves the namespaces into the filesystem folders.

Example:

load from `app\validators`:

`$passwordValidator = validatorFactory->create('PasswordValidator');`

load from `core\validators`:

`$emailValidator = validatorFactory->create('EmailValidator');`

The coolest thing would be if the factory would first try to load the class from app namespace and if not possible from the core namespace. Of course I thought about implementing to the factories create method to try loading the class first from app\validators and if an exception comes up then try loading it from core\validators. But then I would have to implement all the create methods from the different factories that way and I wondered if there is a nice generic solution.

What is the best way to make the factory look in both namespaces for the requested class?

PS: I hope that question is not too silly due to I'm relatively new to such patterns.

Comment: Also, when you are into the usage of namespaces, why would you want to degenerate to generic names (without NS), or do you want the app namespace to take precedence over the core framework? That would create rather unpredictable results.

Comment: I've implemented such pattern without a factory where the app classes are extending the core classes, and there is always an app version of the class in the core as well. When creating the class in the actual app it will override the core version

Comment: The predictability is a good point. Now when you say it it seems to make not so much sense to define namespaces when I don't respect them...

Answer (score 0):

You could rework your autoload function like this, so the error is detectable, if the file doesn't exists:

```
function __autoload($class) {
    $parts = explode("\\", $class);
    $path = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $parts) . ".php";
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        throw new Exception("The class is not loadable");
    } else {
        include_once $path;
    }
}
```

And then in the factory:

```
class ValidatorFactory {

    public static function create($name) {
        try {
            /*
             *  try to include from the core namespace
             */
            $Class = "core\\validators\\" . $name;
            $validator = new $Class();
            return $validator;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            /*
             * if it's not possible, try to include from the app namespace
             * if the validator doesn't exist at all, then we
             * let the user handle the error
             */

            $Class = "app\\validators\\" . $name;
            $validator = new $Class();
            return $validator;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could just use it like this:

```
$myValidator = ValidatorFactory::create("EmailValidator");
```

In your context, i think it would be more suitable to use a static `create()`, but maybe i'm wrong.

You could also document the `create()` methods return value, so that your IDE (netbeans, eclipse, whatever) will know the return type, and show suggestions (I suppose there is a base interface or abstract class in your library for the validators):

```
/**
 * @return \core\validators\IValidator 
 */
public static function create($name) {
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

You could use something like this, but you would need to create factory instances, which isn't the best idea in my opinion, but here you go:

Abstract base class, with a concrete implementation of `create()`

```
abstract class AbstractFactory {

    private $namespaces = array();

    public function __construct($namespaces) {
        $this->namespaces = $namespaces;
    }

    public function create($name) {
        foreach ($this->namespaces as $namespace) {
            $Class = $namespace . "\\" . $name;
            try {
                $instance = new $Class();
                return $instance;
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                // empty
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("No class found");
    }

}
```

An implementation

```
class ValidatorFactory extends AbstractFactory {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(array(
            "app\\validators",
            "core\\validators"
        ));
    }
}
```

And then:

```
$factory = new ValidatorFactory();
$myValidator = $factory->create("MyValidator");
```

Comment: =D that's nearly exactly how my autoloader looks like. The solution is that which I meant to not be generic enough. When I create another factory for other class types which should behave the same way I would have to implement the same stuff again. But Maybe I could save the subnamespace like 'validators' in a property and use this to don't repeat the same creation method over and over...

Comment: I see, but i think, something like this the best that you can do, if you want to use factory methods like this. You could also create a wrapper class around your factory class, which knows the namespaces it should look for, and loops over them, and tries to load one.

Comment: This is a nice idea. I think, I'll try this.